# Splitting fields being Galois

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

For a finite extension $K/F$, $K$ is Galois over $F$ if $\mid  Aut(K/F)\mid=[K:F]$. Is the splitting field of any polynomial containing a separable factor Galois?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re in characteristic $p$, a polynomial could have an irreducible inseparable factor. Example: let $k=\Bbb F_p(t)$, and $F(X)=(X^p-t)(X^p-tX-t)$, two irreducible factors of degree $p$, one inseparable, the other separable. Then the splitting field is not Galois, ’cause not separable.

Comment: this wouldn't happen in a field characteristic 0 right?

Comment: Right, because irreducible inseparable polynomials are only in char. $p$; similarly, inseparable field extensions are a char.-$p$ phenomenon.